# Strange behaviour of C++ compiler

Tags: c++

My concern in this question is not where the bug is but rather why the compiler responds to this bug this particular way. **The bug is in case k==4 in the first loop. The value of "current" can be -1 sometimes which causes the issue.**

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct com
{
    int type,k,ver;
    string s,res;
    bool b;
    com()
    {
        k=type=ver=-1;
        s="";
        b=false;
        res="";
    }
};
int main() {
    int Q,k;
    string W;
    cin>>Q;
    int current=0;
    vector<com> com_his;
    for(int i=0;i<Q;i++) //<--FIRST LOOP
    {
        cin>>k;
        if(k==1)
        {
            cin>>W;
            com t;
            t.type=1;
            t.s=W;
            // if(com_his)
            t.ver=i;
            current=i;
            com_his.push_back(t);
        }
        else if(k==2)
        {
            cin>>k;
            com t;
            t.type=2;
            t.k=k;
            t.ver=i;
            current=i;
            com_his.push_back(t);
        }
        else if(k==3)
        {
            cin>>k;
            com t;
            t.type=3;
            t.k=k;
            t.ver=current;
            // while()
            com_his[current].b=true;
            com_his.push_back(t);
        }
        else if(k==4)
        {
            // cin>>W;
            com t;
            t.type=4;
            // t.s=W;
            current--;
            while(com_his[current].type==3||com_his[current].type==4)
                  current--;
            t.ver=current;
            com_his[current].b=true;//<--THIS IS THE BUG. SOMETIMES "current" can be -1 which causes the issue.
            com_his.push_back(t);
        }
    }
    string s="";
    cout<<"SIZE IS "<<com_his.size()<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<Q;i++)  //<--SECOND LOOP
    {
        k=com_his[i].type;
        cout<<i<<" "<<Q<<endl;
        cout<<"HOWDY"<<endl;
    }
    
    // cout<<"HALLO\n";
    return 0;
}
```

However my concern is why doesn't the compiler say segmentation fault when this happens? For example if I provide this input

```
10
1 lchbfcjtfpsmjrqsdgci
3 19
1 cpcvixlm
1 apdjgjydvpbpvyiy
2 29
4
4
3 9
4
4
```

I get this output in all the different compilers I have tried:

```
SIZE IS 10
0 10
HOWDY
1 10
HOWDY
2 10
HOWDY
3 10
HOWDY
4 10
HOWDY
5 10
HOWDY
6 10
HOWDY
7 10
HOWDY
8 10
HOWDY
9 10
HOWDY
```

And then I get an error. In different compilers I get different errors. While using Hakerrank I got this error:

```
    double free or corruption (!prev)

    Reading symbols from Solution...done.

    [New LWP 73923]

    [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

    Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

    Core was generated by `./Solution'.

    Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.

    #0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50

    To enable execution of this file add

        add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py

    line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".

    To completely disable this security protection add

        set auto-load safe-path /

    line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".

    For more information about this security protection see the

    "Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:

        info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
```

While using Dev C++ 5.11 in windows I get this:

```
Process exited after 8.516 seconds with return value 3221226356
```

While using c++ 14 on online gdb at https://www.onlinegdb.com/ I get this:

```
Compiled Successfully. memory: 2792 time: 0.17 exit code: 134
```

My question is if out of memory accessed occurred in first loop why does the second loop even execute at all? The output of all 3 compilers is same despite their errors being different. So how does the code even reach the second loop?
I'm just trying to understand this behavior.

For MORE INFO:
I was trying to solve this problem:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/simple-text-editor/problem
In this challenge, you must implement a simple text editor. Initially, your editor contains an empty string, S. You must perform Q operations of the following
types:

1)append(W):Append string W to the end of S.

2)delete(k):Delete the last k characters of S.

3)print(k):Print the kth character of S.

4)undo:Undo the last (not previously undone) operation of type 1 or 2 , reverting S to the state it was in prior to that operation.

Input Format

The first line contains an integer, Q, denoting the number of operations.
Each line i of Q the subsequent lines (where 0<=i<Q) defines an operation to be performed. Each operation starts with a single integer, t (where t={1,2,3,4}), denoting a type of operation as defined in the Problem Statement above. If the operation requires an argument, is followed by its space-separated argument t. For example, if t=1 and W="abcd" , line i will be *1 abcd*.

Comment: The canonical answer for this is probably: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/179910.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks this is actually helpful. Is https://www.iso.org/standard/70588.html the official source for latest C++ standards? Or is there any other source?

Comment: That's a particular extension to the standard. You can get drafts of the standard at: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/tree/master/papers. You pretty much have to pay to get the official standard, but the last draft before the standard (e.g., N4835 came just before C++20, the current standard) is easily close enough for most practical purposes (and the draft immediately following the standard will include all the updates that were in the standard itself).

Answer (score 2):

`com_his[-1]` is undefined behavior. To be clear: A runtime error, not a compile error.

Different operating systems and different compilers can handle this however they want to.

Comment: So what you are saying is program will keep on running even after out of bound memory access occurred and then at the end when the program is about to quit it will show the error?

Comment: No, the joy of undefined behaviour is anything can happen, your program might even appear to work correctly most of the time but fail seemingly at random